# how do I send ACK using ruby's serialport gem?

Tags: ruby, macos, serial-port, osx-lion, ruby-1.9

#### gems

serialport (1.0.4)
Authors: Guillaume Pierronnet, Alan Stern, Daniel E. Shipton, Tobin
Richard, Hector Parra, Ryan C. Payne
Homepage: http://github.com/hparra/ruby-serialport/
Library for using RS-232 serial ports.

#### ruby

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
running under rvm 1.10.2

---

I am using this gem on **Mac Lion**, and my device's specifications are as follows.

- 9600bps
- 7bits
- 1 stop bit
- EVEN parity
- **RTS/CTS** are used for send/receive control

The driver I am using is md_PL2303_MacOSX10.6_dmg_v1.4.0.zip
http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/downloads.asp?id=31

After receiving data, I should send ACK back, to let the device know the data was ok.
Here's how I am currently doing.

```rb
sp = SerialPort.new("/dev/serial-device", 9600, 7, 1, SerialPort::EVEN)
sp.flow_control = (SerialPort::SOFT | SerialPort::HARD)
loop do
  data = sp.gets
  p data
  while sp.cts() == 0; end #waiting for the device if it's ok to send
  sp.putc 0x06.chr #ACK
end
```

If the device doesn't receive ACK within 1 second after I get data (`data = sp.gets`), it will send another same data to make sure I get it ok. Currently, I am getting the 2nd same data although I am trying to send ACK like above.
*note `while sp.cts() == 0; end` doesn't take 1 second

To be honest, I am not sure if my code is correct to send ACK.   If anybody can point out where I am doing wrong, it will be a big help.
Thanks

---

#### update

> http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-putc
>   putc(obj)
>
> If obj is Numeric, write the character whose code is the
>   least-significant byte of obj, otherwise write the first byte of the
>   string representation of obj to ios. Note: This method is not safe for
>   use with multi-byte characters as it will truncate them.

so it turns out any of the 4 below will output the same.  This is what I have found so far, but the device doesn't yet recognize any of these as `ACK` and sends me the second same data...
I am thinking it's maybe beacuse of `flow_control`??  (although I tried SOFT, HARD, NONE, SOFT | HARD)

```
~ $ irb
1.9.3p0 :001 >
1.9.3p0 :002 >   File.open('putc.txt', 'w') do |file|
1.9.3p0 :003 >     file.putc 0x06.chr
1.9.3p0 :004?>   file.putc 0x06.ord
1.9.3p0 :005?>   file.putc 0x06
1.9.3p0 :006?>   file.putc 6
1.9.3p0 :007?>   end
 => 6
1.9.3p0 :008 >
1.9.3p0 :009 >
1.9.3p0 :010 >   data = File.read('putc.txt')
 => "\x06\x06\x06\x06"
1.9.3p0 :011 > data.bytes.to_a
 => [6, 6, 6, 6]
1.9.3p0 :012 >
1.9.3p0 :013 >   exit
~ $
~ $ od -a putc.txt
0000000  ack ack ack ack
0000004
~ $
```

---

#### update 2

I tried tail -f /dev/serial-device but it didn't display, or it exited with "busy" error.
 1. using tty.usbserial to send & receive, tailing tty.usbserial. both didn't show anything.
 2. using cu.usbserial to send & receive, tailing cu.usbserial. tail gave me "busy".

so instead, I searched around and found dtruss command to see what's going on behind the scene.

```rb
Process.pid #find this PID
serial_port = SerialPort.new("/dev/tty.usbserial", 9600, 7, 1, SerialPort::EVEN)
serial_port.flow_control = (SerialPort::SOFT | SerialPort::HARD)
loop do 
  serial_port.gets
  while serial_port.cts() == 0; end
  p "before putc"
  serial_port.putc 0x06.chr
  p "after putc"
end
```

I ran this on a terminal, and open another with `sudo dtruss -a -p __PID_FROM_THE_RUBY_CODE__` and I got something like this

```
11812/0xfdd0:   5737859     772     11 read(0xB2, "0\0", 0x2000)         = 1 0
11812/0xfdd0:   5737866     208      0 sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF6FA7B340)         = 0x0 0
11812/0xfdd0:   5737869       5      0 sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF6FA7B330, 0x0)         = 0 0
...
...
11812/0xfdd0:   5739675      16     11 write(0x1, "\"before putc\"\n\0", 0xE)        = 14 0
11812/0xfdd0:   5739685       4      0 sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF6FA7B150)         = 0x0 0
11812/0xfdd0:   5739686       4      0 sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF6FA7B140, 0x0)         = 0 0
11812/0xfdd0:   5739694       9      6 write(0xB2, "\006\0", 0x1)        = 1 0
11812/0xfdd0:   5739709       5      0 sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF6FA7B1B0)         = 0x0 0
11812/0xfdd0:   5739710       3      0 sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF6FA7B1A0, 0x0)         = 0 0
11812/0xfdd0:   5739716       8      4 write(0x1, "\"after putc\"\n\0", 0xD)         = 13 0
```

`write(0xB2, "\006\0", 0x1)` this seems like it's writing `0x06`.  but I am not sure how to read this at all..
the elapsed time 5739694 - 5737859 (receiving data `gets` - sending ACK) = 1,835 micro sec, I believe. so I think I am sending ACK before 1 sec expires...

still no clues why I get the 2nd data. (unless otherwise 1 sec is already passed before I get to send ACK..?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sp.puts 0x06.chr`?  It looks like OSX Lion is still running Ruby 1.8.7 as stock, and that should work.

In OSX Lion I'm able to do this, the second one is the one you want I believe:

```
>> putc 0x06.chr
=> "\006"
>> puts 0x06.chr

=> nil
```

In windows this'll print a funky character... but you can verify using a file in OSX Lion...

```
>> f = File.new('tmp.txt', 'w')
=> #<File:tmp.txt>
>> f.puts 0x06.chr
=> nil
>> f.close
=> nil
>> exit
narada:~ bcochran$ od -a tmp.txt 
0000000  ack  nl                                                        
0000002
```

**Update**

The way you're doing it above seems to work too...

```
narada:~ bcochran$ irb
>> f = File.new('tmp.txt', 'w')
=> #<File:tmp.txt>
>> f.putc 0x06.chr
=> "\006"
>> f.close
=> nil
>> exit
narada:~ bcochran$ od -a tmp.txt 
0000000  ack                                                            
0000001
```

Comment: I'll revise this answer, turns out `0x06.chr` should work fine as I needed it to use it to send `STX` and `ETX`.  Stay tuned.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I am actually running 1.9.3. I edited the question and added the version info.

Comment: have you tried snooping the serial line?  You should be able to `cat`/`tail -f` your serial port file `/dev/serial-device` and see what is going on.  Even better, hook it up to a logic analyzer so you can see the specific timings relative to RTS/CTS.  

I'll try and hook up an FTDI serial device to my logic analyzer and see what happens.